# Google App Script - change the colour of a cell if it matches a condition from string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been banging my head on a performance issue I'm facing with our company google sheet, I need a specific range of cells to be coloured according to the content of 2 strings, right now I achieve this via conditional formatting but the process is rather slow 5m for 550 lines to be coloured, plus conditional formatting recalculates every time I change a filter or sort so not ideal.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

if the colour grading flag is marked, it should read the two promotion strings, past+current and future, and for each week of sales it should colour the cell if it falls in any of the ranges from the two strings

In the example image the article has two promotions in the past+current string both marked as 1-6 Green and separated by a semicolumn (1-6 Green;1-6 Green), for each week of sales i check if the week nr is contained in one of those ranges, if it is colour the cell of the promotion colour corresponding.

Possible colours are Blue, Yellow, Green and Purple being prioritised with Blue=high priority all the way down to Purple=low priority.

If sales nr is 0 then overwrite with a bright red colour.

I have found scripts to change colour but i don't really know how to manipulate them to do something like this.

Here what i got from another website, this just reads a cell content and if that says "open" it colours it:

```
function myColorFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange(2,6,ss.getLastRow());
  var cellRange = range.getValues();

  for(i = 0; i<cellRange.length-1; i++){
     if(cellRange[i][0] == "Open")
     {
       ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange(i+2,6).setBackground("red");
       ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange(i+2,6).setFontColor('white');
     }
  }
}
```

I'd like to run a function like this one when i flag the cell "colour grading flag" and get rid of conditional formatting which is just too slow.

here another example:

[image]

the circled sales cell is in column AO, that falls into week 48, if in column BB there is a promotion that covers that week, colour it with the promotion colour. In this case there is a week 6 to 14 Blue, so columns AY and AZ for that row should be coloured in blue.

Hope that clarifies

Thanks everyone for the precious help

Comment: Can you explain how columns 48, 49 and 50 are red.  I don't see anything in the promotion strings to account for that coloring.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does just what your version did but quite a bit faster.  I'm still having trouble getting my head around you real problem.

```
function myColorFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,6,ss.getLastRow());
  var bA=rg.getBackgrounds();//get all background in the range
  var fA=rg.getFontColors();//get all font colors in the range
  var vA=rg.getValues();//get all values

  for(i=0;i<vA.length-1;i++){
     if(vA[i][0]=="Open")
     {
       bA[i][0]='#ff0000';//i+2 is not necessary inside the array because range starts at column2
       fA[i][0]='#ffffff';
     }
  }
  rg.setFontColors(fA);//sets ones that didn't change and ones that did at the same time.
  rg.setBackgrounds(bA)
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper,

Thanks for getting back to me, I'll try to explain a bit better:

each column corresponds to a week nr, each row to an article nr, the cells in each week contain the amount of units sold for given article. If the amount is 0 then conditional formatting will light the cell with red. 
If content is not 0 i somehow need to read those 2 cells called promotions to understand if the cell/week being analysed falls into any of the promotional ranges, if it does then my cell needs to be coloured like the promotional range it falls into.

Comment: Does each article have a target number of weekly sales?

Comment: How about Red - 0 weekly sales. Blue - >0 to 25%. Yellow - >25% to 50%. Green - >50% to 75%. Purple - >75%. using Math.floor((nr/weekly target) * 100)

Comment: there's no target as articles can be of totally different range, some might sell tens of thousands while others only hundereds.

Comment: I've updated the description with a second visual example, hope that helps to clarify